# Какие символы запрещены в имени службы Windows?

Tags: windows, служба

Какие символы запрещены в имени службы(сервиса) Windows?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/801318

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [информации с сайта MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.servicename(v=vs.110).aspx), имя службы не может быть нулевым и не должна содержать в себе символы ASCII ниже 0x20, а также прямой и обратный слэши.

**Однако!!!** Исходя из собственного неприятного опыта, крайне не рекомендую пытаться использовать в русскоязычной Windows имена, содержащие символы расширенной евро-таблицы (умляуты и прочие подобные символы). Если интересна конкретика, то у меня некорректно работали несколько функций, в т.ч.  `GetServiceKeyName` в тех случаях, когда использовались умляуты (делалось совместно с немцами, у них - работало, у нас - нет).